# Non-isomorphic modules generated by one element

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, modules, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group. I have the $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module, $\mathbb{C}[G]=n_{1}V_{1}\oplus \cdots\oplus n_{r}V_{r}$, where the $V_{i}$ form a complete set of irreducible submodules of $\mathbb{C}[G]$. I know that every $n_{i}$  equal to $1$ because $G$ is abelian.

I'm trying to understand why the submodules are definitely  non isomorphic. How can I prove that ?

I know that its right but I don't know why.

Comment: what about the irreducible modules in  G+G

Answer (score 3):

The irreducible (i.e. simple) submodules are nonisomorphic because they have distinct annihilators.

$V_1$ is annihilated by $0\oplus V_2\oplus V_3\oplus\cdots$ and $V_2$ is annihilated by $V_1\oplus 0 \oplus V_3\oplus\cdots$ and so on.

Answer (score 2):

There are as many non-isomorphic modules as conjugacy classes, so in your notation $r \geq |G|$ since the list is complete. By a dimension argument, you can see that each is $1$-dimensional and can appear only once.

Comment: Thank you! just want to ask, is this also true to the same Q with list not defiantly  complete? and can you please explain why it means that not all the modules are isomorphic? @marlasca23